# How to change a user password?

Tags: c, linux

I m playing with /etc/passwd in my C program.

I want to change a user password. are there a standard linux functions that do a such functions ?

Comment: `/etc/passwd` does not contain passwords in typical Linux distributions

Comment: Many _/etc/passwd_ related questions today. Some homework or lab going on somewhere ?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question in a third time?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Likely. It's around mid-term time for semester Uni's in the US.

Answer (score 0):

- Method 1: `system("passwd <parameters>");`
- Method 2: `*pwent()` [function family](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setpwent) and also [putpwent()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/putpwent).

The question is possibly a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978892/how-do-i-change-a-user-password-in-c-using-linux-system-calls).

Answer (score 0):

Linux stores the password in the `/etc/shadow` file. The second column (delimited by `:` character) in this file against the user name shows the hashed password.

It's best advised to not touch this file and cause harm. If you must, you can use the `vipw` utility for editing